# Javascript replace letter + number regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string containing an URL, containing /p[num], for example www.test.com/list/p12 (p is the page number used for pagination).

This is my attempt to get the URL without the page number in javascript:

```
url = url.replace("\\/p\\d+", '');
```

However, it doesn't replace anything. What am I doing wrong here?

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/t9p95p87/

Comment: You seem to be using regex syntax in a string literal that is passed directly to `.replace()`. Instead use regex literal. `url = url.replace(/\/p\d+/, '')` Your way would work if you passed that string to the `RegExp` constructor. `url = url.replace(new RegExp("\\/p\\d+"), '');`

Comment: If that URL is coming from `window.location` or an `a.href`, and if the part to remove will always be at the start, you could handle it without a regex by modifying the `.pathname` property and assigning it back to the same property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use regexp literal syntax your code works fine:

```
url = url.replace(/\/p\d+/, '');
```

I think what was happening in your code is that the double backslash before the `/p` was ending up being interpreted as a desire to match a literal backslash.